# Issue with edit removed points (not shown)

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I read [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237) and the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

I shared the left image 10 April 2018 with a friend and the right my score at 11 April 2018 9:30 CEST

[image]
[image]

I know that I got 3 accepted edits and an upvote on 10 April 2018.
However now in the reputation log there is only shown 1 accepted edit and an upvote. The [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) showed the same reputation on 10 April 2018 my website:

[image]

I think that one of the following points are not working correct:

> - A post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as removed): −2
> - The account of a user who was the final approver of a suggested edit you made has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as User was removed): −2

This is from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) from 10 April 2018:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "suggested_edit_approval_received",
      "reputation_change": 2,
      "post_id": 49752478,
      "creation_date": 1523362044,
      "user_id": 7185314
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "post_upvoted",
      "reputation_change": 10,
      "post_id": 49747965,
      "creation_date": 1523355130,
      "user_id": 7185314
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "suggested_edit_approval_received",
      "reputation_change": 2,
      "post_id": 49747453,
      "creation_date": 1523345965,
      "user_id": 7185314
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

One of the *"suggested_edit_approval_received"* is edited after my edit. But does that lose reputation? If so why is that not shown?
And why does Stack Overflow shows only one approved edit?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's covered by:

> A post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as removed): −2

as this is the most common case of 'hidden' reputation loss. For the corresponding entry to show up in your Reputation tab, you **must** enable the 'show removed posts' checkbox at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Comment: yeah: [answer is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752359/heatmap-analytics-service/49752478#49752478)